# Set default category

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, default

I would like to set a category by default to one product because we can find it in several categories. eg: In Apple > iPhone et in Smartphones. How I could do that please?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a code on event "catalog_product_save_after" and with the help of this event you can call a method which will call when you save any product.

In this method you can put your code which will get and check the product category. If no category is available then set your category and save product again.

Comment: Dear Ashish, thank you very much for your message but unfortunately I don't have development skills. I tried to edit the field position on the "catalog_category_product" table in database for my product_id but it does'nt work: the category by default still remain the same. https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/361x182q90/924/j1gzMt.png

Comment: In that case you can update that product category from admin

Comment: It would be great! Could I edit the order/position of a category for a product in admin please?